# EndpointVolumeAPI with Python CTypes

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, cherrypy

So I've been working on an Android app that functions as a remote controller for your windows computer, and I've hit a bit of a snag. I want to allow the user to dynamically adjust their computers volume - easy peasy on the android side, apparently a bit more complicated on the windows side. I have a python server (using cherryPy) that also uses PyWin32 to do some simple win32 api stuff - turning off the computer, logging out, beeping etc etc. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, pywin32 does not contain any support for the EndpointVolumeApi that I believe I need to use to adjust the volume. This lead me to (attempt) to use Ctypes - but I'm having a really hard time with it. I'm not sure if it's the python side or the windows programming side (that API is a bit of an nightmare!), but I can't find a good way to jump into the code. I guess my specific question would therefore be - How do I get access to the ISimpleAudioVolume interface through CTypes? What setup do I need to do? Any helper code would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks in advance guy.

Comment: Before NT 6 (Vista) you could do this using the Win32 mixer functions (not too hard, but tedious), but now that API only works per application. The master volume control moved to the COM-based EndpointVolume API. Look into using `pythoncom` or `comtypes`. You could also write an extension module, or use subprocess to call a console utility such as `NirCmd`.

Comment: Using a subprocess to call a console utility - that's really, really clever! I'll definitely give that a shot. If that doesn't happen to work out, are there any good introductory sources on pythoncom or comtypes? I guess the real weakness for me right now is that I know next to nothing about native windows programming (and as awful as it is, I'd prefer not to have to dive too deep!)